# Symfony 2 FOSUserBundle: Override form without defining service

Tags: php, forms, symfony, fosuserbundle

I' m trying to set up FOSUserBundle for my new application, so I want to override the default FOSUser form. As stated in the FOSUser documentation, I have to define my new form as a service before set up the app/config.yml appropriately. My question is why can't I just set up config.yml like this:

```
fos_user:
db_driver: orm
firewall_name: admin_area
user_class: abc\abcBundle\Entity\User
registration:
    form:
        type: abc\abcBundle\Form\Type\UserType
```

In my last application, I used FOSUserBundle along with PUGXMUltiUserBundle and then my (perfectly working) configuration for PUGXM was:

```
users:
    agents:
        entity: 
            class: abc\NikBundle\Entity\agents
        registration:
            form: 
                type: abc\NikBundle\Form\Type\UserType
                name: agent_user_registration_form
            template: abcNikBundle:ManageUsers:newUser.html.twig
```

so I supposed this can also be done with FOSUserBundle. Is it impossible and if yes why?

Comment: You can't set it up like that with `FOSUserBundle` because they don't offer those options. The `PUGXMultiUserBundle` uses a custom registration controller that gets your settings from the user discriminator service.

Answer (score 0):

FOSUserBundle allows you to override it's controllers as described in the doc below

https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/overriding_controllers.md

This doc actually shows you how to override registration controller and from there it's simply injecting your custom form for validation as in any normal controller.

You can also override the templates by finding the original FOSUserBundle templates under "{ROOT_DIR}/vendor/friendsofsymfony/user-bundle/Resources/views" and copying them into "{ROOT_DIR}/app/Resources/FOSUserBundle/views".

https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/overriding_templates.md

It should look like this

```
Resources
└── FOSUserBundle
    └── views
        ├── ChangePassword
        │   ├── changePassword.html.twig
        │   └── changePassword_content.html.twig
        ├── Registration
        │   ├── confirmed.html.twig
        │   ├── register.html.twig
        │   └── register_fail.html.twig
        ├── Resetting
        │   ├── checkEmail.html.twig
        │   ├── email.txt.twig
        │   ├── passwordAlreadyRequested.html.twig
        │   ├── request.html.twig
        │   ├── request_content.html.twig
        │   ├── reset.html.twig
        │   └── reset_content.html.twig
        ├── Security
        │   └── login.html.twig
        └── layout.html.twig
```